# How to store mysqli connection in a seperate php file and call it once needed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

At the moment im using a php connection using session I dont think thats the right or better wya of doing this, I would like to separate the mysqli connection as I will be calling that connection several time through out my code.

Connecting to mysqli

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = "XXXXX";
$password = "YOLO";
$database = "XXXXX";
$localhost = "XXXXX";
$_SESSION['connection'] = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password, 
$database);
?>
```

calling connections in other files

```
include "../storeSQL/sql_Connection.php";
 //SQL QUERY bla bla bla//
$isRealAdmin = $_SESSION['connection']->query($sql);
```

Comment: This is useless. What you need (if you really need it) is a __persistent__ connection.

Comment: Thanks I know this is a bad way of doing it but i cant find a way to do it better. what do you mean a persistent connection?

Comment: I dont think i need persistent connection I just want to know how to connect to mysql by calling it from different file.

Comment: So what is the problem with replacing `$_SESSION['connection']` with just `$connection`?

Comment: Because it wasnt working. which is why I used session to begin with. But I changed it back to as you suggested and for some weird reason its working now. maybe i had something wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended not to save the session in a session (it may lead to injection possible or memory leak). I would recommend you have it like below instead

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = "XXXXX";
$password = "YOLO";
$database = "XXXXX";
$localhost = "XXXXX";
$connection= mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password, $database);
?>

include "../storeSQL/sql_Connection.php";
//SQL QUERY bla bla bla//
$isRealAdmin = $connection;
```

Comment: As I explained above "Because it wasnt working. which is why I used session to begin with. But I changed it back to as you suggested and for some weird reason its working now. maybe i had something wrong in my code."